# Is it possible to identify what data a neural net was trained on?

Tags: neural-network, dataset

For example, if there are 5 major data sets for a certain topic. Would it be possible to see if a deployed network was trained off of one them?

How would one approach this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the loss for a specific dataset, then the most probable set would be the one with the lowest loss.